# helm-comint-input-ring - get error: shell-mode-map

Tags: helm, debugging, shell, variables

windows 10, emacs 26.1, helm 3.0

I use `C-c C-l` (`comint-dynamic-list-input-ring`)
I get something like this:
[image]

But I don't like this. I want to use `helm-comint-input-ring`.
I want to get something like this:

[image]

So I set in my `init.el` the next keybinding

```
(define-key shell-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-l") 'helm-comint-input-ring)
```

But when I start Emacs I get error:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘d:/Programs/emacs/.emacs.d/init.el’:

Symbol's value as variable is void: shell-mode-map

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the ‘--debug-init’ option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

How I can fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Defining key-bindings within \`helm-map\`: getting a \`void-variable helm-map\` error](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2539/defining-key-bindings-within-helm-map-getting-a-void-variable-helm-map-erro)

Comment: (eval-after-load "shell"
  '(define-key shell-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-l") 'helm-comint-input-ring))